# Adobe A/B testing (Selecting CSS class name ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, target, ab-testing

I got a question on selecting goal metric by a clicked an element! is it possible to select an CSS class name instead of an element ID ?  currently tracking clicks is set up correctly like this `(_AT.applyWhenReady([{"action":"trackClick","selector":"#control_control1_control2_btnToBeASuperMan",)`

and jquery selector is tracking ID --> `**#**control_control1_control2_btnToBeASuperMan`

for the complicated reason, the button ID will render differently base on different condition, I have tried  so that I only have to select one element, but many of my javascript have much error because of it.

and so i want it to track CSS class name instead- like-->  .`btnToBeASuperMan`

is this possible? any suggestion on about solved this problem would be great

appreciation your help thanks.

Comment: Can you show your actual file instead of snippets?

Comment: the file is actually generated by adobe target on page load so I guess ... I can not modify that file.

Comment: To select the element I want to track, adobe provided an iframe for user to select what to track which I think is a limitation,(the iframe allow me to selected and element ID and not element CSS name )